# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: json, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to read a whole text chunk of tweeter data scrapped from a tweeterAPI. The text data looked like:

```
{
 "contributors": null,
 "coordinates": null,
 "created_at": "Thu Jun 07 14:57:00 +0000 2018",
 "entities": {
              "hashtags": [],
              "symbols": [],
              "urls": [
                       {
                        "display_url": "twitter.com/i/web/status/1\u2026",
                        "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1004739005676695552",
                        "indices": [111, 134], 
                        "url": "https://xxxx"
                       }
                      ],
              "user_mentions": []
             },
 "favorite_count": 0,
 "favorited": false,
 "geo": null,
 "id": 1004739005676695552,
 "id_str": "1004739005676695552",
 "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
 "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
 "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
 "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
 "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
 "is_quote_status": false,
 "lang": "es",
 "metadata": {
              "iso_language_code": "es",
              "result_type": "recent"}...
```

of which the pattern repeats.

I wanted to use json library in python 3 to parse each tweet, but I ran into an error of

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I believe "line" is already decoded as it's a string type, but I couldn't wrap my head around to debug this. I would appreciate any input or advice, thank you.

```
all_scrapped_tweets = []
with open(my_text_file, 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    twt = json.loads(line)
    all_scrapped_tweets.append(twt)
```

Comment: Your sample before the `...` is missing the final `}` to close the json. My suggestion to debug would be to paste what you get back from the API into a code editor that highlights starting and ending brackets like {} and match them up to make sure you're working with complete json data.

Comment: Thank you, it turned out the text file was corrupted- Thank you for the hint! Truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample before the ... is missing the final } to close the json. Looks like your data was corrupted, as you indicated in the comments.